# How to load a Page in WPF from a folder inside my solution

Tags: wpf, frame

I have this `Grid` with `Frame` inside:

```
<Grid Name="GridMain" Grid.Row="1">
    <Frame Name="MyFrame"
           NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
           Source="home.xaml"/
</Grid>
```

Now this `home.xaml` page loads successfully and is located inside my root solution.

Now inside my solution I have folder called `Pages`. I want to load another `Page` that I have inside this `Pages` folder, so I try to do it this way:

```
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages"

<Grid Name="GridMain" Grid.Row="1">
    <Frame Name="MyFrame"
           NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
           Source="{pages:home.xaml}"/>
</Grid>
```

But this does not work.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Neither the first XML ([XAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language)) sample nor the second XML sample seems to be valid XML. How could any of the tools for WPF accept this? Was this is in the original source or was this retyped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Source` property to the `Pages/home.xaml`:

```
<Frame Name="MyFrame"
       NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
       Source="Pages/home.xaml"/>
```

The `Source` property should be set to a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).